# Does anyone know how to make my 3d model's outline look like a boiling line animation effect? like Ed, Edd n Eddy

Tags: animation, objects, 2d, freestyle, outliner

I'm trying to make it look like a boiling line animation like "Ed, Edd n Eddy" from Cartoon Network or "Cuphead." I have an outline now, but how do I make this boiling line? If you know the question, please answer it. here, for example.

[image]

Comment: please add sketches, images how it should look like. You shouldn't prerequisite that everybody knows the Cartoon you are talking about...

Comment: You could probably get the effect you are looking for by making the outline of the character (not the "fill") a grease pencil object (either by drawing it as a grease pencil object, or by using a _line art modifier_ ), and then adding a _Noise Modifier_ to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image] (It's 6 frames but looks like 2)

Looking at your example GIF, the line isn't changing randomly, it's two outlines alternating. You can achieve that by adding noise to your freestyle thickness, and animating this noise with a driver. If you want this noise to be repeatable, use `fmod(frame,` **x**`)`, where **x** is the number of unique deformations (in your GIF it's just two). Below the process of creating the animation seen above:

[image]

Please note that you need to add something to the result of `fmod`, as the result sometimes is `0` and it seems there's a bug in Blender currently, crashing Blender for the `0` seed.